# Something like new but to allocate 2 rooms

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

I have a member function that must create two objects of its class (in memory). So I must return a pointer "p", I want to access the objets by p[0] and p[1].  All I know is the keyword new, to allocate memory for one object. Is there something similar to allocate contigous memory for 2 objets ? I can also create a 2 cells array (two pointers) by using the keyword new two times, but I preferer an easier solution (p[0] and p[1]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 MyClass * p = new MyClass[2];
```

and remember to delete it with:

```
delete[] p;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), it will take care of memory management for you.

```
#include <vector>

// This will dynamically allocate an array of 2 instances
// of you MyClass type
std::vector<MyClass> classes(2);

// now you have classes[0] and classes[1]
```

`std::vector` is resizable, and will take care of all memory management overhead for you (you don't need to call `new` or `delete` in this case).

Comment: I thought of Vector, but i need the 2 objets to stay in memory even after the execution of the function, so that's why I think i must allocate memory.

Comment: `std::vector` dynamically allocates the memory for you, but you are correct in that you have to manage the scope of the vector object itself.  Generally, you should avoid using raw pointers in your code.  Consider making your `std::vector` have a scope that is sufficient to hold your objects.  Since you know you have to both `new` and `delete` them anyway, the required lifetime is already well understood.